PgAgent Job Ends but gets restarted again
I have a pgagent installed on ubuntu 22.04. Then I scheduled One job with Multiple job steps.
At the scheduled time job starts and ends successfully. But then restarts again!!!!!.This loop never ends. What is the reason and how to prevent that??
